# NSPopover - hiding standard window possible?

Tags: macos, cocoa

In my Mac app, I want to use a NSPopover, activated by a NSStatusItem. Activating works like a charm, but I would like to get rid of the standard window (white or HUD), that is provided by the NSPopover, and use my own view instead. Does anyone know if that is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, it is not possible -- we tried hard and ended up reverting to the 10.7 way of using a custom class.. check MAAttachedWindow

---

well with enough swizzling and posing it'd be possible of course... but that is very evil and at least as much work as your own class!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try MAAttachedWindow.